# Cannot sync dataset to ontology object

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-phonograph

I have dataset with one of the column "Comments" which is of type string, but when I try to sync this dataset to ontology object, I get below error.

`RemoteException: INVALID_ARGUMENT (Phonograph2:ElasticsearchInvalidRequest) with instance ID : {params=errorDetails=Bulk indexing failed because of errors while indexing to lime. IndexResponses (up to 5 responses displayed): [{"index":"ri.phonograph2.main.index.6472a600-bead-4392-8c25-1292a4b9da2e","type":"dummy-map-aircraft-notes-for-testing","id":"b6915a48ed3dda24314c6a56443c1ea66d3aec197fb22557155c67ba54b22f9e","status":400,"error":"ElasticsearchException[Elasticsearch exception [type=illegal_argument_exception, reason=Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"comment.raw\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.`

I am not able to understand this with my limited knowledge, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Ontology uses Elastic Search to index its objects. You receive an error, because Lucene, the indexing engine, only supports strings with a length of up to 32766 characters.

One common workaround is to use binary instead of string, but I am not 100% sure if that is supported by the Ontology.

You can either truncate the column, so it fits into the index, or contact the support, maybe they have a hidden workaround.